# How do I add a variable to one of the variables in the item codeigniter price (php)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How do I add a variable to one of the variables in the item codeigniter price (php)
i have a variable :

```
$shipping =  10000;
```

and cart session :

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item){
    if($item['discount'] == "0"){
        $harga_before = $item['before'];
        $harga_after = $item['price'];
    }else{
        $harga_before = $item['before'];
        $harga_after = $item['price'];
    }
// result is
    $data_order = array(
        'id_product'        => '1',
        'product_name'  => 'ferari',
        'harga_fix'     => '100' + $shipping,
        'harga_before'  => '150',           
    ),
    array(
        'id_product'        => '2',
        'product_name'  => 'lamb',
        'harga_fix'     => '70',
        'harga_before'  => '85',            
    );
}
```

how to add `$shipping` to one of the item prices? thank you

Comment: `'harga_fix'     => $harga_after + $shipping,`

Comment: i'm sorry I only thicken $shipping. ok i change

Comment: And you might need to fix the syntax error! That last array I think is a mistake, but it will definitely be causing a compilation error

Comment: Please let us know if your get any fatal error